# Modifying GVIM Themes/Toolbars

Tags: vim, gvim, themes

I have this problem, that I cannot seem to figure out.

On one Operating system, centOS, I have a look that I like.

On Ubuntu, the look is different. I don't know where the discrepancy lies.

[How do I customize the gvim toolbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/11289/how-do-i-customize-the-gvim-toolbar)
[Is it possible to change the toolbar icons in gVim?](https://superuser.com/questions/194931/is-it-possible-to-change-the-toolbar-icons-in-gvim)

All similar questions, but I don't feel they are addressing specifically what I am looking for.

I want the theme of one gvim to exist on Ubuntu. What can I do to make that happen.

[image: first]

[image: second]

I want the first image(Ubuntu) to look like the second image(centOS).

If that isn't possible, how Can i get a "File Edit tools syntax" toolbar/menubar on the first image?

Comment: Dunno about the icons, but you can easily get the menu bar with `:set guioptions+=m`.

Comment: I think this depends on your desktop environment.

Comment: In "recent" versions of Ubuntu, the menubar is displayed at the top of your screen instead of in the window as usual. There's probably an option somewhere that disables that feature.